# A login function failing to authenticate , PHP

Tags: php, sql, authentication

Hello im having trouble understanding why my authentication keeps on failing. Ive tried many debug methods and i guess im stumped. Keep in my mind im a beginner still and for now security is not a issue. I just want it to work.

So for my Registering script i have users enter a username and password

```
            $username  = $_POST['username'];
            $password  = $_POST['password'];
```

// Post Data being saved

```
            $createTable = $db->prepare("CREATE TABLE `$username` (Title varchar(40) ,
                                                    About   varchar(1000) , 
                                                    Chapter int(4),
                                                    Img varchar(100) , 
                                                    Url varchar(50)) ");

            $createTable->execute();
```

/// creates a table for user

```
            $Register = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO library (id, 

username, password) VALUES ($id ,
'$username','$password')");
            $Register ->execute();
```

// insert the data into the library table. Library has the users and passwords

```
                echo 'user sucessfully registered';

                $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['pass'] = $password;
```

The problem i have is authenticating this for the login.
A login function is called with the two SESSION variables used as the parameters.

```
function login($SentUser , $SentPass)

      {

echo 'trying to log in '.'<br>';

    require_once 'Connection.php';
    $user = $SentUser;
    $pass = $SentPass;

    /// check data base for match user and pass
        $sth = $db->prepare('SELECT username , password from `library` where username = ? And password = ? ');

        $sth->bindParam(1, $user);
        $sth->bindParam(2, $pass);
        $sth->execute();


        while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
        echo 'user : ' . $row['username'] , '<br>';
        echo 'pass: ' . $row['password'] , '<br>';
        echo '<br>';
            }
        .
        // fetchcolumn returns true false if select took a row or not.
if($sth->fetchColumn() != false) { /// This is where the code fails as it almost always goes to the else case.

            $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
            $_SESSION['pass'] = $pass;
            $_SESSION['passed'] = TRUE;
            echo 'Welcome '.$user.'<br>';}
        else
            {

                echo 'failed authenticate'.'<br>';

            }
```

For added clarity here is the connection.php that is being called. It basically just connects me to the database giving me the $db object.

```
<?php


$config['db'] = array(
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'dbname' => 'mywebsite'
    );




$db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['db']['host']. ';dbname=' . $config['db']['dbname'] , $config['db']['username'] , $config['db']['password']);

?>
```

Comment: why do you create a table for every user?

Comment: This website just keeps track of scraped information specific to what a user has entered. So each user has their own table. Its not the most efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned `library` table has users/passwords. So, it must be having only one row per user. Change code like below:

```
   if($sth->rowCount() == 1) {
      //row exists, so user exists
      $row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      echo 'user : ' . $row['username'] , '<br>';
      echo 'pass: ' . $row['password'] , '<br>';
      echo '<br>';

      //set session
      $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
      $_SESSION['pass'] = $pass;
      $_SESSION['passed'] = TRUE;
      echo 'Welcome '.$user.'<br>';
   } else {
      //auth failed
      echo 'failed authenticate'.'<br>';
   }
```

Comment: thank you , can u tell me what i did wrong . im still new at the sql functions

Comment: In the line `while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))`, you have already fetched the row. Now there will be no rows left to fetch. So, `if($sth->fetchColumn() != false) {` will always return `false`

Comment: So when u select something u put it in a reserve. And when u fetch it it takes it out of the reserve?

Comment: Another problem i just saw was i foolishly forgot to include a session_start() on the register.php so when it sent it's variables. It went blank.  Sorry for have to look through my code :(